# font size depending on container width? only in mobile

Tags: css

I encountered a strange problem which I don't know how to solve. 
Seems that the font size displayed is depending on the width of a container:

For example this is with width:100%

[image]

And this is the same with width:50%

[image]

font-size is 24pt.

But most strangely, this happens only when I activate the mobile icon in chrome / see it on my phone. On desktop version, it does not matter:

[image]

and

[image]

So this is bothering me a lot because other parts of the page have the same font-size but it's showing differently.

I'm not the author of the full CSS so I may be missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Alas, without a repro we can't help you without resorting to guessing. You'll need to debug and narrow down the issue, post a minimal repro here.

Comment: So you mean this is not the default behavior, and should be debugged?